# help with fixing reverting token contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging

I have been trying to interact with a smart contract deployed on the ropsten test network but have a problem sending ethers in exchange for tokens ( Transaction reverted: Error in contract code). 

 Below is the contract source:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC827/ERC827Token.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract GenericToken is ERC827Token, Ownable {


  string public name        = "Generic Token";
  string public symbol      = "GEN";
  uint8  public decimals    = 8;


  uint256 public initialSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals); //   1 billion tokens max
  uint256 public totalAirdropTokens = 800000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals); // 800 million tokens for drop
  uint256 public totalBonusTokens   =  100000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals); // 100 million tokens bonus
  uint256 public tokensForTeam   =  50000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals); // 50 million tokens for team
  uint256 public tokensForPool  =  50000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals); // 50 million tokens for pool

  mapping(address => bool) blacklist;

  enum blacklistToggle { screen, unscreen }
  blacklistToggle public blacklistState = blacklistToggle.screen;

  address public receiver = 0x5087293ecbbDE04da046250C270b02Cf9b6fB657;

  uint256 alreadyAirdroppedTokens;
  uint256 alreadyIssuedBonusTokens;


    //TODO: initialize round times
  uint256 public airDropRoundOneTime;
  uint256 public airDropRoundTwoTime;
  uint256 public airDropRoundThreeTime;
  uint256 public airDropEndTime;

  uint256 public bonusPrice1 = 0.006 ether;
  uint256 public bonusPrice2 = 0.01  ether;
  uint256 public bonusPrice3 = 0.016 ether;

  uint256 public bonusAmount1 = 50000;
  uint256 public bonusAmount2 = 30000;
  uint256 public bonusAmount3 = 20000;

  uint256 public dropAmount;


  constructor (uint256 _dropAmount, 
                  uint256 _airDropRoundOneTime, 
                    uint256 _airDropRoundTwoTime, 
                    uint256 _airDropRoundThreeTime,
                    uint256 _airDropEndTime ) public {

    totalSupply_ = initialSupply;
    dropAmount = _dropAmount;

    airDropRoundOneTime   = _airDropRoundOneTime;
    airDropRoundTwoTime   = _airDropRoundTwoTime;
    airDropRoundThreeTime = _airDropRoundThreeTime;
    airDropEndTime        = _airDropEndTime;

    // balances[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
    // emit Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, initialSupply);
  }


  function setBonusAmounts(uint256 _bonusAmount1, uint256 _bonusAmount2, uint256 _bonusAmount3) public onlyOwner {
    bonusAmount1 = _bonusAmount1;
    bonusAmount2 = _bonusAmount2;
    bonusAmount3 = _bonusAmount3;
  }


  function setRoundTwoTime(uint256 _newRound2Time) public onlyOwner {
    airDropRoundTwoTime = _newRound2Time;
  }


  function setRoundThreeTime(uint256 _newRound3Time) public onlyOwner {
    airDropRoundThreeTime = _newRound3Time;
  }

  function setBlacklistMode(uint intToggle, uint256 _dropAmount) public onlyOwner {
    blacklistToggle _blacklistState;

    if (uint(blacklistToggle.screen) == intToggle) {
      _blacklistState = blacklistToggle.screen;

    } else if (uint(blacklistToggle.unscreen) == intToggle) {
      _blacklistState = blacklistToggle.unscreen;
    }

    blacklistState = _blacklistState;
    dropAmount = _dropAmount;
  } 





  function() external payable {
    claimAirdrop(msg.sender);    
  }


  function claimAirdrop(address _beneficiary) public payable {

    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
    uint256 tokens;

    require(validTransaction());

    if (blacklistState == blacklistToggle.unscreen) {
      blacklist[_beneficiary] = false;
    }

    if (weiAmount < bonusPrice1) {
      require(totalAirdropTokens > alreadyAirdroppedTokens);
      require(!blacklist[_beneficiary]);

      tokens = dropAmount;
      transfer(_beneficiary, tokens);

      blacklist[_beneficiary] = true; 

      totalAirdropTokens += dropAmount;

      }
    if ( (weiAmount >= bonusPrice1) && (weiAmount < bonusPrice2) ) {

      require(alreadyIssuedBonusTokens < totalBonusTokens);
      tokens = bonusAmount1;

      transfer(_beneficiary, tokens);

      alreadyIssuedBonusTokens += bonusAmount1;     
      }
    if ((weiAmount >= bonusPrice2) && (weiAmount < bonusPrice3)) {

      tokens = bonusAmount2;

      require(alreadyIssuedBonusTokens < totalBonusTokens);

      transferFrom(owner, _beneficiary, tokens);

      alreadyIssuedBonusTokens += bonusAmount2; 

      } else {
      require(alreadyIssuedBonusTokens < totalBonusTokens);

      tokens = bonusAmount3;

      transfer(_beneficiary, tokens);

      alreadyIssuedBonusTokens += bonusAmount3; 

    }

    _forwardFunds();
  }



  function validTransaction() internal view returns (bool) {
    bool withinPeriod = now >= airDropRoundOneTime && now <= airDropEndTime;
    return withinPeriod;
  }

  function _forwardFunds() internal {
    receiver.transfer(msg.value);
  }





}
```

what am i doing wrong and how can i refactor, modify or simplify my contact to get it working?

Comment: How do you send ether to the contract? How much are you sending? How the contract was created? Do you have a transaction hash? Did you check if a require is failing? Also check transfer, they only allow 2300 gas to the child contract.